# Как запретить исчезновение блока при переводе курсора

Tags: jquery

Мудрю что-то типа всплывающей подсказки. Есть два элемента расположенных непосредственно один за другим, при наведении курсора на первый появляется потомок второго,соседнего (подсказка), необходимо чтобы на этот элемент, при необходимости, можно было перевести курсор и он не исчезал до тех пор пока курсор не покинет его. У меня просто ступор, не могу понять как это реализовать.
Разметка такая:

```
<a class="linkblok" href="#" title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.">SomeLink</a>
 <div class='block'>
   <span class='selftext'>Ut blandit nibh faucibus arcu sodales, quis pellentesque sem auctor.</span>
 </div>
```

Вот  [**фидл**](http://jsfiddle.net/NHEj3/)

Прошу помочь знающих, заранее всем спасибо.

Comment: :) А ларчик просто открывался...  Спасибо, подходит.

Теперь, когда все прояснилось пришла идея даже сделать так 
http://jsfiddle.net/NHEj3/2/

Comment: в вашем коде hover по много раз вешается, это плохо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/NHEj3/1/